# python input function to input a table and print the content of the table

Tags: python, csv, input, output

I  have the following codes in python:

```
pd = input('table.csv')
```

where table.csv contains (a, b, c) are the column names in this table):

```
a, b, c
49,3,-1
2,101, 5
```

And I want to print out the first column of this table.csv file.

I have tried several ways, such as print(pd['a']). Or

```
col = input('a') or col = pd['a']
print(col)
```

However, I keep getting error:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

How should I print out the content of this csv table?

Comment: `pd` is a string. I recommend importing the csv using pandas, so you can access columns by name.

Comment: I know how to do it in pandas, but this is what is required to do (using python input function).

Comment: So it's homework? And you want us to do it for you?

Comment: It is a problem related to a project. I am curious to know where the problem is with this method to deal with the data